# how do I add totals to a label when check the checkbox and then click submit?

Tags: asp.net

I have two checkboxes that prepopulate a radiobutton. When I select yes on the checkbox it open the radio button that's checked as true with text as a number. I would like to know how to select a single checkbox and display it as a total when I click submit button and it display my single checkbox number as a total in a label end if I select and checked both checkboxes it must add up both checkboxes radiobutton button numbers and display as a total so if single checkbox is selected display the single total end if both checkboxes is selected add up the two numbers and display total in a label when you click submit. Any help will do and be well appreciated Thanks

Heres my code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim number1 As Double
    Dim number2 As Double
    Dim answer As Double
    Dim total As Integer

    number1 = Double.Parse(RadioButton1.Text)
    number2 = Double.Parse(RadioButton2.Text)

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        answer = number1
        answerLbl.Text = answer.ToString()
    ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        answer = number2
        answerLbl.Text = answer.ToString()
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        answerLbl.Text = total.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Can you add a period or two in there? It's very hard to read.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev good effort but I think we need line breaks too :)

Comment: @Basic I ended up just formatting the code. I tried to put in punctuation but my eyes started to bleed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what your looking.

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then   
    answerLbl.Text =( Double.Parse(RadioButton1.Text)+ Double.Parse(RadioButton2.Text)).ToString()

    ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    answerLbl.Text =RadioButton2.Text
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    answerLbl.Text = RadioButton1.Text
  End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Guys the codes look right but ive tested it. Still doesnt work if I check a single Checkbox1 that opens a radio button that is true with a number 3500 and click submit it give the right answer, if I check a single Checkbox2 that opens a radio button that is true with a number 2000 and click submit it give the right answer but if I check Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 it gives only Checkbox1 answer 3500 which is wrong if I check both it must add up the two and give a answer of 5500. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @user1983152, i have updated the answer ,try this it will solve your issue.

Comment: Hey Kiran1016 that is what i was looking for thank u very much just one last question can i display the radiobuttons(numbers) and total values in a mdb database for each time you click submit to view whose interested?

Comment: Please mark it as answered if it worked for you and your question can you be more clear,am not getting your point.

Comment: Hey Kiran1016 I got a total field  in my database for instance I click Checkbox1 that opens the radiobutton with a number 3500 and I click submit it gives me a total of 3500 in a label how do I display dat actual total in a mdb database